# RecyclerView issues : only populating data when the phone is in portrait but does in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I am facing the very strange issue. When I am working with portrait mode data is not populating the `RecyclerView` but does in the Landscape mode. 
But when I have tried it with emulator than it is working fine in both screen orientation.

Manifest file:

```
 <activity android:name="user.com.hlthee.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            />
```

XML file:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    app:cardElevation="24dp"
                    android:elevation="24dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/adherence_text"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                            android:text="Adherence"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/adherence_text"
                            android:id="@+id/action_with_adherence"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

THis is my java file:-

```
actionWithAdherence=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.action_with_adherence);

        actionWithAdherence.setLayoutManager(new GridAutofitLayoutManager(this,200));

        ArrayList<Action> actionListWithAdherence=database.fetchDataFromAdherenceTable();

 actionWithAdherence.setAdapter(new DashboardAdherence(this, actionListWithAdherence));
```

Solution Tried:

Adding of `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`
but didn't help. I have also read from Internet that saving and restoring `savedInstanceState` might help. But I think this is only for saving the state ( i.e what was the state before moving to another `activity`.)

EDIT:-

Adaptor class:

```
public class DashboardAdherence extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdherence.AdherenceHolder> {
List<Action> actionList;
Context context;
private View layoutInflater;

public DashboardAdherence(Context context, List<Action> actionList)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.actionList=actionList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    System.out.println("Size is "+actionList.size());
    return 9;
}

@Override
public AdherenceHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adherence_dashboard, viewGroup, false);
    return new AdherenceHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdherenceHolder adherenceHolder, int position) {

    Action action=actionList.get(position);

    adherenceHolder.actionName.setText(action.getAction_id());

    adherenceHolder.actionAdherence.setValue(action.getUserPercentage());
    adherenceHolder.actionAdherence.setText("55");
    adherenceHolder.actionAdherence.setUnitVisible(true);


    //circleProgressView[i].setBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

}


public class AdherenceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private CircleProgressView actionAdherence;
    private TextView actionName;

    public AdherenceHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);

        actionAdherence=(CircleProgressView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_adherence);
        actionName=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_name);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HealthVitalsFunction {

   SharedPreferences app_preferences;   
    RecyclerView actionWithAdherence;  
   DbHelper database;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        //set basic settings for app.
        app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Constants.setTokenDB(app_preferences.getString("token", ""));
        database = new DbHelper(MainActivity.this);



        /*-------------------------------- Action with the Adherence------------------------*/

        actionWithAdherence=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.action_with_adherence);
        //second parameter 3 represents it has 4 column
        actionWithAdherence.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
        //actionWithAdherence.setLayoutManager(new GridAutofitLayoutManager(this,200));

        ArrayList<Action> actionListWithAdherence=database.fetchDataFromAdherenceTable();

        actionWithAdherence.setAdapter(new DashboardAdherence(this, actionListWithAdherence));

}


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

     }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (exit) {
            finish();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 3000);
        }

        super.onBackPressed();

    }

}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

   /* splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
            universalApk false
        }
    }*/
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "user.com.hlthee"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        /*release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }*/
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //for bottom bar
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    //for splash screen
    compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
    //for volley
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    /*compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'*/
   // compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    /*compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'*/
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.6.7@aar'
    compile 'com.github.jjobes:SlideDateTimePicker:v1.0.4'
    //graph library
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:v1.5.8'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.3.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.2.original@aar'
    //Google Material Icons
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.6.0.2@aar'
    /*compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.0'*/
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
    //compile files('libs/PDFRenderer-0.9.0.jar')
    //To show the thumbnail of pdf
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.4.0'
    //Comment this line before production
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
    //library for chart
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:v1.5.8'
    //library for timelineView
    compile 'com.github.alorma:timelineview:2.3.0'
    //for constraint layout
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'
    //for circular view
    //compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    //for applozic chat api
    compile project(':mobicomkitui')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2'
    //for junit
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //for mockito(framework for making test writing process)
    //testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    //for the curved image view . use in the goal
    compile 'com.github.developer-shivam:crescento:1.0.0'
    //for animated image views
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    //universal image loader to load the image.
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    //for adherence progress circular bar
    compile 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.2.9.1'

    //for the sectioned recycler view
    compile 'com.github.IntruderShanky:Sectioned-RecyclerView:2.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

fetchDataFromAdherenceTable() method.

```
public ArrayList<Action> fetchDataFromAdherenceTable() {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();

        ArrayList<Action> actionList=new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(" select * from "+adherenceActionCOlumnTableName, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

            Action action=new Action();

            action.setAction_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(adherenceActionCOlumn_id)));
            action.setUserPercentage(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(adherenceActionCOlumn_adherence)));

            actionList.add(action);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return actionList;

    }
```

Adapter xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <at.grabner.circleprogress.CircleProgressView
        app:cpv_maxValue="100"
        app:cpv_textSize="15dp"
        app:cpv_textColor="@color/white"
        app:cpv_unit="%"
        app:cpv_unitSize="10dp"
        app:cpv_unitColor="@color/white"
        app:cpv_unitScale="1"
        app:cpv_rimColor="@color/secondary_background"
        app:cpv_rimWidth="10dp"
            app:cpv_barWidth="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/action_adherence"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Exercise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try using basic layout managers like linearlayoutmanager or gridlayoutmanager. and put all of your java code

Comment: All java code means. adapter class and GridAutofitLayoutManager class?

Comment: I have tried to replace         actionWithAdherence.setLayoutManager(new GridAutofitLayoutManager(this,200));
 with         actionWithAdherence.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4)); but no success.

Comment: yes please add the main class code too

Comment: can you add your build.gradle file?I don't see a problem in these files. maybe your appcompat or support library versions are old

Comment: added @masoudvali

Comment: have u checked u are getting list from database in potrait mode using debugger

Comment: Yes, I am getting the data from the db. @Androidjack

Comment: paste your fetchDataFromAdherenceTable method.

Comment: added @Androidjack

Comment: what are the android versions on your emulator and your real device?

Comment: Emulator Android version 6.0.0 and phone 5.1.1

Comment: that's very odd. try linearlayoutmanager instead of grid ones.

Comment: Ya bro, It is working with linearlayoutmanager.. @masoudvali

Comment: add your adapter item xml too

Comment: Added @masoudvali

Comment: change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` of your item linearlayout to wrap_content and use grid layout manager

Comment: No help @masoudvali

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Your activity is starting in portrait mode or Landscape mode ?.Put some background colour to your parent layout ,(red) so that we can make sure layout is in correct place.Is it working with linearLayoutManager ?

Comment: Activity  is starting in portrait mode by default but but data is not shown, but when I change the orientation of phone to the  Landscape mode, then the data populate and shown. Yes it working fine with the linearLayoutManager. @sunilsunny

Comment: Hey thanks for everyone for suggestions. I got the solution, how silly of me.Just changed the above view's( view above the linear layout) height to the wrap_content from match_parent.